# Error with IndexOutOfBoundsException in while loop

Tags: java, arraylist, error-code

I am writing a program that merges two sections of a list.

What I am trying to do is get the next value of both lists and add them to a new (third) list.

Here is my code:

```
int count = 0;
int amount = 1;

while (listOne.size() != count && namesList.size() != count) {
    uValues.add(namesList.get(amount) + " - " + listOne.get(amount));
    count++;
    amount++;
}

System.out.println(uValues);
```

The error is generated on:

```
uValues.add(namesList.get(amount) + " - " + listOne.get(amount));
```

Thanks for your help or suggestions! :)

Comment: `amount` starts at 1, and arrays are 0 indexed so that could be part of the problem.

Comment: When they are different sizes, how would I get around that?

Comment: You start amount from 1, not 0. Array and list indices are zero based in Java. Initialise amount to 0 and it should work

Comment: Yes, this worked. The while loop also made sure that error won't come. Thanks!

Comment: At the moment your while loop will terminate when count gets to the size of the shorter of the lists. If that's the behaviour you want, great.  If not, you might need to ask a new follow on question...